# how to send notification to another user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification

im trying to create a badge system similar to stackoverflows. i noticed that stackoverflow is able to send a notification to another user. for example, if i create a question, and 10 people upvoted my question, i receive a badge, not the current_user doing the upvoting.

how can i do that in rails? it seems sending a message to another user is out of the scope of flash messages. i did some research and maybe the faye gem seems like a possibility? however im not positive though. i was watching the railscasts and it seemed maybe better for a chatting system? is push-notification the way to go?

what would be a good way to do this? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest to use this gem: https://github.com/dapi/gritter_notices

It is well handle with this problem, but it has two drawbacks:

1. Documentation on russian
2. Binding to the gritter

If you choose to use it, see what version of gritter you use. As I remember, the version of original gritter gone forward a bit.

[This part of code does what you need.](https://github.com/dapi/gritter_notices_example/blob/master/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb)